# Leaflet Map not rendering Tiles correctly

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm building a map with `react-leaflet` and in the first load sometimes most of the tiles aren't visualized as you can see below:
[image: react-leaflet-map tiles not working]

I've gone through several stack overflow question and what I've done is:

- Include the leaflet CSS and JS in the `index.html` file
- Include the leaflet CSS directly in the component file
- A `useEffect` that runs on every render and calls the method `map.invalidateSize()` taken by the `useMap()` hook
- A `useEffect` that runs on first render and calls the method `map.invalidateSize()` taken by the `useMap()` hook
- Use the `useMapEvents()` hook and when the maps load run the `map.invalidateSize()` method taken by the `useMap()` hook

Whenever I resize the browser window Leaflet renders all the tiles correctly [image: react-leaflet-map tiles working as expected]

Has someone encountered the same problem? How have you solved it?